# HTML entity decoding with oracle DBMS_XMLGEN.convert

Tags: oracle, xml

Here, I am trying to convert the value, where I don't understand I am going wrong. Your help is highly appreciated!

```
Here I am#44; THis is me there#39;s nowhere else on earth I rather be Here I am#44;
```

to

```
Here I am, THis is me there's nowhere else on earth I rather be Here I am,
```

For this I used the following query which didn't work, Can you please tell me where I am wrong?

```
select DBMS_XMLGEN.convert(REGEXP_REPLACE('Here I am#44; THis is me there#39;s nowhere else on earth I rather be Here I am#44;', '(#[[:digit:]]+;)','&\1'), 1 ) as message from dual;
```

Comment: WITH x AS (SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(REGEXP_REPLACE('Here I am#44; THis is me there#39;s nowhere else on earth I rather be Here I am#44;', '(#[[:digit:]]+;)','&\1'), 1 ) AS message FROM dual)
SELECT message, UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE(message) conv_message from x;

Comment: @Raj Can you please put this in answer that works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is

```
WITH x AS (SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(REGEXP_REPLACE('Here I am#44; THis is me there#39;s nowhere else on earth I rather be Here I am#44;', '(#[[:digit:]]+;)','&\1'), 1 ) AS message FROM dual) SELECT message, UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE(message) conv_message from x;
```